# htaccess of virtual subdomain with subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

currently i have achieved

www.username.domain.com to redirect to domain.com/folder1/folder2/index.php?id=username

with my current .htacceess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$  http://domain.com/general/user/index.php?id=%1 [P,L]
```

i want to achieve this

`www.username.domain.com/pagename/` to redirect to `domain.com/folder1/folder2/next.php?id=username`
`www.username.domain.com/pagename/variable` to redirect to `domain.com/folder1/folder2/next.php?id=username$val=variable`

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rule (place after yours):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^pagename/([^/]*)$  http://domain.com/folder1/folder2/next.php?id=%1&val=$1 [P,L]
```

This will work for both `www.username.domain.com/pagename/` and `www.username.domain.com/pagename/variable` (for 1st URL value of `val=` will be empty string).

**P.S.**
I assume `$` character is a typo in your 2nd destination URL (`domain.com/folder1/folder2/next.php?id=username$val=variable`) and it should be `&` instead.

Comment: Thank you ...didnt see your post up til now it worked. sorry if i may still ask... do i need to put the first two lines of ur code before another page i want to add e.g

Comment: for example 

'RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^pagename/([^/]*)$  http://domain.com/folder1/folder2/next.php?id=%1&val=$1 [P,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^pagename2/([^/]*)$  http://domain.com/folder1/folder2/next2.php?id=%1&val=$1 [P,L]'

Comment: i think i got it...thanks...for every new url i have to place the rewrite cond again....

Comment: One more question: How can i make the subdomain be assigned a particular favicon different from the main domain's favicon

Comment: @EnoBassey 1) Let's assume you have all favicons in `domain.com/favicons/` folder; 2) Name each icon after domain name, e.g. `www.kitten.domain.com` = `domain.com/favicons/kitten.ico`; 3) Use this sort of rule: `RewriteRule ^faicon.ico$ http://domain.com/%1.ico [P,L]` (do not forget to add those 2 RewriteCond before this rule as this rule should only be triggered for subdomains)